# Generating random integers with given probabilities

Tags: haskell, random

I need to generate an infinite stream of random integers, with numbers to be in range [1..n]. However the probability for each number p_i is given in advance thus the distribution is not uniform.

Is there a library function to do it in Haskell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to expand on dflemstr's answer, you can create an infinite list of weighted values using [Control.Monad.Random](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.3/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html) like this:

```
import Control.Monad.Random
import System.Random

weightedList :: RandomGen g => g -> [(a, Rational)] -> [a]
weightedList gen weights = evalRand m gen
    where m = sequence . repeat . fromList $ weights
```

And use it like this:

```
> let values = weightedList (mkStdGen 123) [(1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 10)]
> take 20 values
[2,1,3,2,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,3,3,2,2,2,3]
```

This doesn't require the IO monad, but you need to provide the random number generator that's used for the stream.

Answer (score 12):

As people have pointed out there is a function in `Control.Monad.Random`, but it has pretty poor complexity.  Here is some code that I by some coincidence wrote this morning.  It uses the beautiful Alias algorithm.

```
module Data.Random.Distribution.NonUniform(randomsDist) where
import Data.Array
import Data.List
import System.Random

genTable :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> (Array Int a, Array Int Int)
genTable ps =
    let n = length ps
        n' = fromIntegral n
        (small, large) = partition ((< 1) . snd) $ zip [0..] $ map (n' *) ps
        loop ((l, pl):ls) ((g, pg):gs) probs aliases =
            let prob = (l,pl)
                alias = (l,g)
                pg' = (pg + pl) - 1
                gpg = (g, pg')
            in  if pg' < 1 then loop (gpg:ls) gs (prob:probs) (alias:aliases)
                          else loop ls (gpg:gs) (prob:probs) (alias:aliases)
        loop ls gs probs aliases = loop' (ls ++ gs) probs aliases
        loop' [] probs aliases = (array (0,n-1) probs, array (0,n-1) aliases)
        loop' ((g,_):gs) probs aliases = loop' gs ((g,1):probs) ((g, -1):aliases)
    in  loop small large [] []

-- | Generate an infinite list of random values with the given distribution.
-- The probabilities are scaled so they do not have to add up to one.
-- 
-- Uses Vose's alias method for generating the values.
-- For /n/ values this has O(/n/) setup complexity and O(1) complexity for each
-- generated item.
randomsDist :: (RandomGen g, Random r, Fractional r, Ord r)
            => g                           -- | random number generator
            -> [(a, r)]                    -- | list of values with the probabilities
            -> [a]
randomsDist g xps =
    let (xs, ps) = unzip xps
        n = length xps
        axs = listArray (0, n-1) xs
        s = sum ps
        (probs, aliases) = genTable $ map (/ s) ps
        (g', g'') = split g
        is = randomRs (0, n-1) g'
        rs = randoms g''
        ks = zipWith (\ i r -> if r <= probs!i then i else aliases!i) is rs
    in  map (axs!) ks
```

Comment: I just tried this "Total   time   55.59s" against the implementation here: http://idontgetoutmuch.wordpress.com/2014/08/26/haskell-vectors-and-sampling-from-a-categorical-distribution/ "Total   time   11.09s" sampling 2*10^7 samples in both cases. Perhaps this isn't a fair comparison as one uses System.Random and the other System.Random.MWC.

Comment: Yes, I would assume generating random numbers would dominate in my code.  It also needs specialization, which might happen automagically with -O2.

Comment: Using a different random number generator I get "Total   time   20.31s" better but still not as good. I haven't tried specialisation yet. Also memory usage is not good. I would expect 4 + 8 bytes for each entry in the two tables so that should be 2*12*10^7 bytes so less than 1G. I am seeing about 5G. I am probably being naive though. And I still haven't finished reading Devroye and Vose. Who would have thought you could have so much fun with random numbers.

Answer (score 6):

[`Control.Monad.Random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.3/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html) offers this function in form of [`fromList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.3/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html#v%3afromList)`:: MonadRandom m => [(a, Rational)] -> m a`

You can use it in the `IO` Monad with:

```
import Control.Monad.Random
-- ...
someNums <- evalRandIO . sequence . repeat . fromList $ [(1, 0.3), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.5)]
print $ take 200 someNums
```

There are other ways of running the `Rand` Monad as you can see in that package. The weights do not have to add up to 1.

**EDIT:** `Rand` is apparently lazier than I thought, so `replicateM n` can be replaced by `sequence . repeat`, as @shang suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `System.Random.Distributions.frequency`

```hs
frequency :: (Floating w, Ord w, Random w, RandomGen g) => [(w, a)] -> g -> (a, g)
```

See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Euterpea-1.0.0/docs/System-Random-Distributions.html