# Does sequencing an infinite list of IO actions by definition result in a never-ending action? Or is there a way to bail out?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, language-lawyer, proof, io-monad

This was actually something I wanted to understand with [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77902757/what-is-the-most-terse-way-of-reading-single-keystrokes-up-to-one-specific-key), but I misworded it by giving for granted the solution would somehow have to build on `sequence` and `repeat`, so I got an intersting answer, which is definitely useful to solve the problem at hand, but I didn't actually solve my curiosity as well, so I'm rephrasing the quesition as in the title.

As you can see from the linked question, I initially wrote

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- takeWhile (/= 'q') <$> sequence (repeat getChar)
  print "you pressed q"
```

thinking `x` would be a finite-length `[Char]`.

But I'm now under the impression that I've not "just" used the wrong tool above (`takeWhile`, a pure function), but that there's actually no (orthodox) tool at all to bail out of that `IO [Char]` that is `sequence (repeat getChar)`.

Am I correct?

If not, then how do you bail out of that?

Beware, I'm not asking now the same question as [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77902757/what-is-the-most-terse-way-of-reading-single-keystrokes-up-to-one-specific-key). I'm looking for a solution that does make use of `sequence (repeat getChar)` and still manages to get to the `print "you pressed q"` action, or the explanatin of why such a solution doesn't exist.

Comment: If you can't change `sequence (repeat getChar)` I can't see any way to bail out. If you allow `sequence (repeat customGetChar)` then you might be able to hack a custom getter which appends the keys to some `IORef` and then exploits exceptions to bail out. But that looks too hacky to me, I dislike such an abuse of exceptions -- I'd rather (locally) change the `IO` monad to some other IO-based monad that allows bailing out. Perhaps `ContT ... IO` could be enough.

Comment: You might use [`timeout`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/System-Timeout.html), but it would always return `Nothing`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575573/loop-not-terminating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `sequence` an infinite list of `IO` operations, you can't bail out via "pure" program logic.  So, you are correct that there is no "orthodox" tool to bail out of `sequence (repeat getChar)`.

The only way to bail out is to invoke an `IO` effect to do "impure" bailing, for example by raising an exception, killing the thread, exiting the program, or similar.  In these cases, you can't easily return a value, so this wouldn't be very useful for your use case.  Alternatively, instead of bailing out, you can "cheat" and use unsafe lazy I/O, which allows you to execute an initial prefix of the infinite list of actions and inspect the initial prefix of the returned list.  You can either continue processing the list indefinitely or "abandon" the list after processing some finite number of elements.

In general, though, either of these approaches are going to be bad practice, at least for your problem.

If you want to write a proper monadic action that reads characters until the first `'q'`, then the right way to do it with elementary Haskell code is something like this:

```
getToQ :: IO String
getToQ = do
  c <- getChar
  if c == 'q' then pure [] else do
    cs <- getToQ
    pure (c:cs)
```

The technical reason you can't use `sequence` to implement this logic is that this is a fundamentally monadic algorithm but `sequence` is "only" an applicative combinator.  Applicative combinators can't use the results of applicative actions to influence the "structure" of the computation.  When you `sequence` an infinite list of `IO` actions, you have committed to executing an infinite loop, and the results of the actions cannot change this into a finite loop, except as a side effect (exception, etc.).  In particular `sequence` can't implement the part of `getToQ` where we inspect the return value `c` and decide whether the rest of the computation is going to be `pure []` or a recursive call to `getToQ` to do more `getChar`s.  You can see this from the following (simplified) definition of `sequence`:

```
sequence [] = pure []
sequence (x:xs) = do
  a <- x
  as <- sequence xs
  pure (a:as)
```

See how the returned `a` value from the `x` action cannot be used to influence whether or not the `sequence xs` action in the next line executes?  That's how `sequence` differs structurally from `getToQ`.

Now, there are some packages, like `extra` and `monad-loops` that provide monadic combinators that can be used to succinctly write the equivalent of `getToQ`.  For example, from `monad-loops`, the `unfoldWhileM` will do exactly what you want:

```
unfoldWhileM (/= 'q') getChar
```

There's nothing magical about these combinators.  A simplified implementation of this combinator would be:

```
unfoldWhileM :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m [a]
unfoldWhileM p x = do
  a <- x
  if p a then do
      as <- unfoldWhileM p x
      pure (a:as)
    else pure []
```

See how this combinator, in contrast to `sequence`, is fundamental a non-applicative, monadic combinator.  It uses the return value `a` from the action `x` to determine the structure of the rest of the computation: (i) recurse to execute more `x` actions; or (ii) end the computation.

Comment: When you write that `squence` is an applicative combinator, do you mean that its signature `(Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)` restricts `m` more than it actually needs, and that fundamentally `sequence` is the same as `sequenceA` and so all it truly needs from `m` is that it be an `Applicative`? Well, I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55486718/why-sequence-requires-monad-if-applicative-would-suffice) answers the question: `sequence`s `Monad` constraint is unnecessary, so you truly mean `sequence` needs and uses `Applicative`.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly right.

Answer (score 2):

`sequence (repeat getChar)` has type `IO [Char]`. That type says that it's a **single** `IO` action which when *run to completion* will produce a `[Char]`.

Of course *we* know that this single action was produced by stitching together a series of smaller actions, but there's no way for that to help us. There's no way to unpick it again into the individual steps and run them one at a time so that we can look at each individual `getChar` result and decide whether to continue. A value of type `IO [Char]` simply has no ability for you to run it partially and get part of the result and then decide whether you want to continue; that is a much more complicated interface than `IO` provides. Once you've got an `IO [Char]` your choice is to run it or not to run it; that's it.

(You can very easily write programs that do what you want of course, but you don't do it by combining the actions into a single action that unconditionally runs them all and then trying to process the resulting action to add the conditions; you do it by putting the conditions in as part of a more complicated combining operation than `sequence`)

This isn't even specific to infinite lists of `IO` actions; exactly the same "problem" happens with something like this:

```
takeWhile (/= 'q') <$> sequence (replicate 10 getChar)
```

`sequence (replicate 10 getChar)` will get 10 characters from stdin and then sequence them into a list in the order they were read. That's simply what that code means. Applying further computations to the resulting list (like `takeWhile (/= 'q')`) doesn't change what `IO` actions happened, it just computes a pure value from the pure string that was produced *after* all the I/O was done. Try it and see; if you type `q` before 10 characters it will still keep calling `getChar` a total of 10 times, and you won't see any output printed until you hit the 10th key. `takeWhile (/= 'q')` is like a stage in a pipeline; it changes what comes *out* of the pipeline, but it cannot change the behaviour of the stages before it to make them do less I/O.

(And that's a *very* good thing; if we're writing code that interacts with a user we're probably doing lots of I/O that doesn't produce any result that's read by downstream code. If the downstream code could "switch off" some of the I/O we do by not reading its result it would be a nightmare to control what the user experience is going to be. If we *want* to let calling code control exactly what bits of I/O are done, we have to provide those bits as separate I/O actions and let *it* decide how to compose them)

The simple answer is that the program you are trying to express is **not** "run all of these actions, combine their results into a list, then filter the list". But that's exactly what `takeWhile _ <$> sequence _` *means*. If you want to do something else, write different code. In particular `sequence` is simply not what you want if you want to run your actions one at a time, examine the results, and decide whether to continue. But neither is anything else that gives you a single `IO [Char]`; don't combine your actions into one if you want to apply separate logic!

---

This can seem like `IO` is very different from normal Haskell, since in normal Haskell you *can* apply `takeWhile (/= 'q')` to an infinite list produced by an infinite computation and stop running part way through. But note that when you do that there is no way for `takeWhile (/= 'q')` to *change* the computation that it is post-processing. If the list you apply it to was produced by `let xs = xs :: [Char]`, applying `takeWhile` can't stop that from running forever (and nor can any other function that examines the list in any way). In exactly the same way, if you write code that specifies an `IO [Char]` that runs forever (like `sequence (repeat getChar)`) then nothing you apply to it after the fact can convert into an `IO [Char]` that runs for a finite time and produces a different value (with different observable effects!).

But it's not that `IO` makes lazy things non-lazy. When you have an `IO [Char]`, the `[Char]` that is produced is still lazy in exactly the same way as an ordinary `[Char]`. You can see this with something like:

```
getInfiniteChars = do
  c <- getChar
  pure $ repeat c
```

`take 10 <$> getInfiniteChars` will work just fine, because `getInfiniteChars` is a *finite* `IO` action that produces an *infinte* `[Char]`, so we can run the action to completion and then post-process the result lazily; there's no need to "interrupt" the I/O and decide to stop it. `sequence (repeat getChar)` is simply an action doing an infinite amount of I/O, rather than a finite action producing an infinite `[Char]`.

It's the `IO` part of `IO [Char]` that is "not lazy", but this isn't special; there are loads of other types that can't be consumed lazily (`Integer`, `Int`, `Char`, strict `Text`, etc). `IO` is simply like those, not like lists. Don't think of a `IO [Char]` as an actual string that exists and is simply tagged as being impure; the `IO [Char]` value is more like a **program** that *could* produce a string when you run it (which is why it can produce different strings when you run it multiple times; `getChar :: IO Char` could not possibly model console input if it was "a `Char` value tagged as impure", after all). You can't consume the program lazily in order to run parts of it and not others, but you can consume its result lazily once it has run to completion and handed over a result.

(You *could* do something like fork a thread to run the action and interrupt it from another thread while it's part way through; but there's no way to examine the memory managed by that thread and figure out which bits correspond to "the first part of its result" or "the character it just read" - at least not without dropping WAY down into low-level code that would make it hard to even recognise Haskell-level values - so that doesn't help you do what you're after either)

---

Now the elephant in the room is this: there *is* such a thing as lazy IO, and its even in the prelude in the form of things like `getContents :: IO String`. This does produce a string which can be filtered with things like `takeWhile`, and how much of the string you read influences how much I/O actually takes place.

However, it is **impossible** to implement something like `getContents` with "normal" Haskell. It requires the use of `unsafeInterleaveIO`, which is a special low-level operation involving compiler internals (and as the name suggests, is potentially unsafe), breaking the normal rules of the language. So it is probably possible for you to use things like `unsafeInterleaveIO` to implement a magic `lazySequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]` that allows consumption of the resulting `[a]` to drive whether the individual `IO a` actions are run. But it would require tricky and advanced code, and *still* wouldn't be anything you could just apply to `sequence (repeat getChar)` after the fact; you would still need to replace `sequence`.

It is something of a consensus now that lazy I/O like `getContents` might have been a mistake to include in the prelude. It *is* very convenient for some simple programs, and being able to write those without needing to import things is arguably good. But lazy I/O can very easily lead to some very surprising behaviour causing bugs, which is *especially* harmful for beginners, so arguably it should have been kept out of the basic prelude that beginners typically learn from. And that's the *pre-existing* lazy I/O operations; writing your own lazy I/O by using `unsafeInterleaveIO` directly is not something to take lightly.

This answer didn't feel complete without acknowledging the existence of lazy I/O, but I would very much recommend against solving this kind of problem with it.

Comment: With reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785956/5825294), executing in `IO` monad means that `fromList $ [(1, 0.3), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.5)]` is a `IO Int`, but `sequence . repeat` is applied on it. And then yes, that's passed to `evalRandIO`, but `sumNums <- that stuff` makes me think that the action must be executed there to generate an infinite list. But apparently that list is.. lazy? And indeed `take 200` is applied on `someNums`, i.e. inside the `IO` monad returned by `evalRandIO`. I guess this is another case like the one you make about `getContents`?

Comment: @Enlico After tracing the source a bit I'm 99% sure that's unrelated. Note that  `evalRandIO` has type `Rand StdGen a -> IO a`; the computation that's fed into it is **not** in the `IO` monad, it's in the `Rand Stden` monad. And you can confirm by entering this in ghci: `:t evalRandIO . (sequence `asTypeOf` _) . repeat . fromList $ [(1, 0.3), (2, 0.2), (3 :: Int, 0.5)]`. This reports `sequence` having inferred type `[RandT StdGen Identity Int] -> Rand StdGen [Int]`; it's sequencing an infinite generator, not an infinite I/O action.

Comment: @Enlico Ultimately the `Rand` data type is a wrapper around a `StateT`. By just doing `import Control.Monad.Random` you get the lazy version (there's an alternate strict one now; there doesn't seem to have been when that answer was written) based on [Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html), where you can see right up the top of the docs an explicit note that this `StateT` is lazy enough for `evalState (sequence $ repeat $ _)` to be meaningful. So that's all it is; IO is strict, but this isn't IO.

Comment: @Enlico The command in my first comment should have been ``:t evalRandIO . (sequence `asTypeOf` _) . repeat . fromList $ [(1, 0.3), (2, 0.2), (3 :: Int, 0.5)]``; I always mess up the markdown when there are backticks inside an inline code snippet.